# .NET ClickOnce detection on IE 11 Edge Render / Spartan on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-preview, internet-explorer-11, clickonce

I have a web page that is a pre-launch page for a .NET ClickOnce application.  It attempts to determine if ClickOnce support is available in the user's browser.  Right now, we check using all of the following ways:

1. User agent - this works in a lot of older cases
2. `navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-ms-application"]` - this works in some FF and Chrome cases
3. `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_CLICKONCESUPPORT"]` - this works for more recent IE versions

However, none of these work for IE 11 in Edge mode or in Spartan on Windows 10 Technical Preview.  What is a valid way to do this in that configuration?  Is there a valid way?

I should add that ClickOnce in general (it's a .NET 4.x app) works fine.  It even works in Spartan.  I just don't seem to be able to confirm that for the user.

Comment: Have you confirmed ClickOnce is otherwise support in the current preview release?  I hope your not depending to many hours trying to support a preview version of an operating system which won't even use IE11 unless configured to do so.  What build are you using?

Comment: Yes, ClickOnce works fine.  It even works in IE 11 (I should add this is in Edge rendering mode; if you use the Trident engine it's fine).  Since Spartan = IE 11 Edge it has the exact same issue.  I'll update the question to make this clear.  And we have to support IE 11 anyway because of corporate users.

Comment: Spartan is not equal to IE.  IE11 Edge is an option today but it won't be come release.  If you want to support IE11 disable Edge on IE11

Comment: It's not reasonable to ask customers to do that, and it's completely besides the point of the question.  The Spartan engine is the IE 11 Edge engine (cf. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/01/22/project-spartan-and-the-windows-10-january-preview-build.aspx) and we need to be able to support that engine, which is the original question.

Comment: Your asking about a problem with beta software in a browser that will change in a future build of a preview version of Windows.  Windows 10 will contain two browsers Project Spartan and IE11 which will remain unchanged.  You linked to an old invalid article about IE and Spartan.  Have you actually tried turning off Edge mode in IE11?  You will have to wait until Click Once supports Edge mode.

Comment: Yes, turning off Edge mode works.  And Click Once supports Edge mode.  As I said, the application works, 100%, in non-Edge and Edge mode.  The article is not "old and invalid" - it's current and accurate.  None of this has anything to do with answering the actual question of how to detect Click Once.

Comment: It has everything to do with your problem.  You said that IE11 is in Edge mode, come release of Windows 10, IE11 WILL NOT support Edge mode.  It will only support the legacy mode, the option to enable Edge mode within IE11, will be removed by the time Windows 10 is released.  Perhaps I don't understand what isn't working because you claimed that the only time your detection is NOT working is when your using either Project Spartan or IE11 in Edge mode. The article is from January, the description of Edge mode is not accurate, read the more recent article about Edge mode.

Comment: This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/03/24/updates-from-the-project-spartan-developer-workshop.aspx) is accurate as you can see Edge mode will not be supported in IE11, Project Spartan is **NOT** IE11, and Project Spartan will NOT have legacy mode support.  So details that surround Project Spartan and IE11 on Windows 10 is important, since your question is about Click Once detection with both of those browsers, so the accurate current plans are important. Why can't you just detect if the browser is in Edge mode, and since you already know it supports it, proceed form there.

Comment: Assuming Edge supports Click Once is probably a reasonable answer.  If you make it an answer, then I'll accept it.

Comment: Um, for clarity...edge mode in IE11 is not the same as edge mode in Spartan...any more than edge mode in IE10 is the same as edge mode in IE9.  The term "edge mode" was introduced along with "document mode" in IE8.  It refers to the "highest standards support available."  Also, the Spartan rendering engine is a fork of the IE Trident engine.  You can expect differences between Spartan edge mode and IE11.x edge mode, in much the same way that today's IE11 edge mode is different than it was when IE11 was originally released.  Please don't assume the browsers will be the same.

Comment: For clarity: right now, at 10049, they are nearly the same - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/03/30/quot-project-spartan-quot-in-the-windows-technical-preview-build-10049.aspx tells us this (comment points out they are slightly different), and matches the previous link I sent as well.  _In the future_, they won't be.  I need to support 10049 today.  At some currently unstated future time, IE will lose the ability to optionally use the new engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your detection works with IE11.  It also works with alternative browsers other then Project Spartan.

One can assume that since Project Spartan supports Click Once, that specific supportability of Click Once detection, isn't actually required.  Instead of trying to detect if Project Spartan supports Click Once, check if the user agent indicates thatthe Project Spartan is being used

Comment: For the sake of completeness: this assumes it's impossible for the user to turn off ClickOnce in .NET 4 through normal actions in Windows 10, which appears to be the case.  If the app was on .NET 2.0/3.5, that would be an issue, since that can be added/removed as a feature in Windows 10.

Comment: @MikeBaz - Even if you were using a previous version of .NET that wasn't the native version in Windows 10 at the time, and the user had not installed that Windows Feature, you could then handle it like every other agent where supportability is not known.  Of course, since Spartan will offer very little "legacy" support, its unlikely a previous version of Click Once would even work in it [ I have no capability to check myself ].